# Sound Effect, Footsteps in Snow

Tags: snow, effect, footsteps

How would you make the footsteps in snow sound either via synthesis or recording/sampling?
I would prefer the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squeezing bags of corn starch sounds a lot like walking in the snow.

Answer (score 2):

To get a slushier sound, do what Nick said above, cornstarch in a pillowcase but make the mixture 50/50 cornstarch and birdseed.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the corn starch, but adding a bit of rice gives a nice crispy texture as well. Also, adding dishwasher salts can give this texture.

Manipulating it with your hands rather than feet gives you more control over the sound.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Walking on gravel can also provide an effective 'snow' sound with some help from EQ. Though it misses the 'squeak' of the shoes compressing the snow.

Answer (score 0):

I've put corn starch in pillowcases, then recorded a foley artist walking on it. Creates that perfect scrunch, but also makes quite a mess as the powder gets everywhere. You can add some rock salt to get a grittier sound if desired.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go further by adding an icy element to it

Answer (score 0):

Squeeze custard powder or corn starch in rubber gloves. Sounds great!

Answer (score 0):

Ive got a 25min snowy footsteps library ,recorded last winter. Lots of different types of snow, from crusty deep to frozen hard packed. 
Contact me at gimaudio {(at.)} gmail.com if you like.

Best wishes
Mikkel

Answer (score 0):

I live in a place without snow, even during the winter.
Walking over sand, make something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a Winter Kontakt library that will contains footsteps on about 16 different types of snow. Check this demo video [here](http://youtu.be/mnYNd0LhLhM). You can go to my [site](http://www.signoaudiodesign.com) and download a free footsteps patch for Kontakt. This "Female boots footsteps patch" is not the final version but a test drive version of the patch, so let me know.

Cheers

Bernard

http://www.signoaudiodesign.com

Comment: Here's a FREE Fresh snow footsteps patch for Kontakt 

http://www.signoaudiodesign.com